# displaying contacts in checked listview for deletion

Tags: android, contacts

Can anyone tell me how should i display the phone number and the contact name in a custom list view? The user should be able to select them and delete as per his wish

Comment: Your question is far too broad. Please search for a solution (tutorial, open-source project, blog post) that implements this functionality, and then come back if you have more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Once I made a demo related to contacts.  Not sure what quality it is but here is a link to project for you: https://github.com/pelotasplus/ContactsDemo

Good luck!